# OSError: [Errno 107] in Jupyter docker container when processing large files

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working with Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) files in a docker container. I have mounted a backup file containing ~16 million entries of SQL, which I want to operate on. The entries in the backup file are of PostgreSQL dialect, and are raw SQL somewhat as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table_name([column_names separated by comma]) VALUES (values separated by comma);
```

I am having problems dealing with this file in Jupyter. I tried to read it line by line and insert the lines as raw SQL into PostgreSQL database. This worked for a couple dozen thousand rows but then the `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected` appeared. Then I tried to start writing from the line where I last left off but the error appears soon enough again.

Next, I tried Python's readlines:

```
with open("/path/to/file.backup", "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

but that fails as well, with the same error.

It might be of importance that the backup file is mounted to the docker container as a volume. The container is run using `docker-compose` and the relevant parts of the docker-compose.yml are here:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/myuser/path/to/notebooks:/tf/notebooks
    - /c/Users/myuser/path/to/backup_file:/tf/data
  ports:
    - 8888:8888
  user: root
```

The .ipynb file I am working with resides on the same level but in a different directory than the backup file. Both directories are mounted from outside the container.

I am wondering whether this could be like a memory or CPU issue (I did `docker stats` on my container, lot of CPU usage during handling of the file), but it is still weird to me that it gives this error.

Whenever this error occurs, I am unable to access my notebooks directory in Jupyter, and I have to restart entire Docker (taking the container down and up is not enough).

Relevant logs from Jupyter container:
`[E 11:48:39.552 LabApp] Error while saving file: notebooks/populate_db.ipynb [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: '/tf/notebooks/populate_db.ipynb'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 471, in save
        self._save_notebook(os_path, nb)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 293, in _save_notebook
        with self.atomic_writing(os_path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 213, in atomic_writing
        with atomic_writing(os_path, *args, log=self.log, **kwargs) as f:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 103, in atomic_writing
        copy2_safe(path, tmp_path, log=log)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 51, in copy2_safe
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
        with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: '/tf/notebooks/populate_db.ipynb'
[W 11:48:39.556 LabApp] 500 PUT /api/contents/notebooks/populate_db.ipynb?1591098519530 (172.18.0.1): Unexpected error while saving file: notebooks/populate_db.ipynb [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: '/tf/notebooks/populate_db.ipynb'
[W 11:48:39.556 LabApp] Unexpected error while saving file: notebooks/populate_db.ipynb [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: '/tf/notebooks/populate_db.ipynb'
[E 11:48:39.556 LabApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab?",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|695ba9e2|ce49a1a69d34d68ccd56352b0c805223|1591003618",
      "Origin": "http://localhost:8888",
      "Content-Length": "6836",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1590754680|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MDI2OWM5NjVlMjhmNGJjOTgzZjZkNDg3ZDMyNmMyMDc=|f2b616ab71fecbbeac60cfa57455e7d49cdf3563ef00729e1adc3f0c4d17f86e\"; pga4_session=34c2a786-ecfe-48b3-8682-c56b64236b64!3p1/6xx3V2lJFdQouLkwpXmndM8=; _xsrf=2|695ba9e2|ce49a1a69d34d68ccd56352b0c805223|1591003618; PGADMIN_LANGUAGE=en",
      "Pragma": "no-cache",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    }
[E 11:48:39.556 LabApp] 500 PUT /api/contents/notebooks/populate_db.ipynb?1591098519530 (172.18.0.1) 20.92ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab?`

I have not experienced this before, and seem unable to solve. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one took this up, I decided to post my own non-conclusive answer.

The problem (socket error) seems to occur when too much I/O operations occur over a websocket. Since a docker container communicates with docker volumes via websockets, there is a limit to the number of operations per unit of time that can take place.

In my case there was a lot of reading from a volume and simultaneously a lot of writing to a volume.

Possible solutions include:

1. limiting operation amount per unit of time
2. building the volumes into the docker image that is being run, if that is possible

Option 1 could be too slow for some applications, and option 2 might not always be possible due to the changing contents of the volumes.